# Can pack200 be used on individual java classes?

Tags: java, deployment

I see that pack200 can be used on JAR files, but can it be used on individual class files?

My webserver receives tons of requests for x.class.pack.gz which doesn't exist, before serving x.class.

If Java requests x.class.pack.gz, does that mean it's possible to pack individual classes?

Running pack200 without a JAR file as input doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

The Pack200 format was designed to allow greater compression across multiple class files in order to reduce the size of large .jar files. This is because the .zip format (on which the .jar format is based) only compresses each file individually and doesn't account for redundancies across different files in the archive.

You should look into what is causing the requests for individual .class files on your server. Chances are you have a JNLP for a Java Applet or Webstart app that is not packed as .jar files. The default mechanism for a JNLP/Applet class loader causes the request for the packed version of a file - and .jar is assumed. Having these as .class files is confusing the class loader. You can either re-package the offending Applet/Webstart app as a .jar or change the JNLP or Applet tag to have the `jnlp.packEnabled` attribute set to `false` to prevent the requests.

For more info see [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/tools/pack200.html) on Pack200 and the `jnlp.packEnabled` attribute.